# How do I display text and a picture vertically inline inside a white box?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS and therefore not any good (yet). As a school assignment I'm making a website. my layout will be a header on the page-top, which is in a fixed position, so it scrolls with you. under the header it will be some space and then four white boxes on grey backgrounds, where each box will contain one image and a paragraph of text. My problem is to get the image and text to horizontally inline with each other e.g. text on the left hand side and the picture on the right side.

```css
body {
    font-family:"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #29B1B1;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin: auto;
}
.top-ribbon-outer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#29B1B1;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
}
.top-ribbon-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav {
    float: right;
}
li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#logo {
    font-family:"Oswald";
    color: white;
    font-size:32px;
}
Body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font-family:"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#innhold {
    display: table
}
#innhold img {
    margin: 3px;
    width: 35%;
}
#topboks {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 3em;
    width: 74%;
    margin-left: 13%;
    margin-right: 13%;
}
.boks {
    background-color: white;
    width: 74%;
    margin-left: 13%;
    margin-right: 13%
}
#kontakt {
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-ribbon-outer">
        <div class="top-ribbon-inner">
             <h1>first last</h1>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>item1</li>
                    <li>item2</li>
                    <li>item3</li>
                    <li>item4</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="innhold">
    <div id="boks1">
        <div id="topboks"> <span>Lorem dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>

            <img src="app.jpg" alt="app-interface" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boks">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="boks">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="boks">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="kontakt">
        <!-- will be a footer with contact information etc.-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use table tag inside div which will encapsulate span tag and img tag on separate columns

Answer (score 0):

You have your text in a SPAN but not your images. Wrap each image in a SPAN just like the text already is. Make sure the wrapper DIV has width set wide enough to accommodate both spans.

```
<div class="row" width=100%>
<span class="picture">photo here</span>
<span class="article">text here</span>
</div>
```

Each ROW consisting of a picture on one side, and a text on the other is a DIV.

Inside that DIV, you add two SPANS -- one span for the picture, one span for the text.

Then you can adjust the PADDING of each span and div, controlling the background colors of each to get the borders you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you...

HTML code :-

```
            <div class="container">
            <div class="top-ribbon-outer">
                <div class="top-ribbon-inner">
                     <h1>first last</h1>

                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li>item1</li>
                            <li>item2</li>
                            <li>item3</li>
                            <li>item4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="boks1">
                <div class="innhold topboks">
        <span> 
         <p>
Lorem dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
 Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
 remaining essentially unchanged. 
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
         <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif" alt="" />   
         </span>
         </div>
        </div>
      <div class="innhold boks">
         <span> 
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
remaining essentially unchanged.
 It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
         <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif" alt="" />  
         </span>
     </div>
      <div class="innhold boks">
        <span>
           <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, 
remaining essentially unchanged. 
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
         <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif" alt="" />       
        </span>
       </div>
        <div class="innhold boks">
          <span>  
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing 
      and typesetting industry. 
    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
       </p>
       <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/img_tree.gif" alt="" />   
      </span>
      </div>

          <div id="kontakt">
                <!-- will be a footer with contact information etc.-->
            </div>

    </div>
```

CSS Code :-

```
body {
    font-family:"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #29B1B1;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin: auto;
}
.top-ribbon-outer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#29B1B1;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin:auto;
}
.top-ribbon-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
nav {
    float: right;
}
li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
#logo {
    font-family:"Oswald";
    color: white;
    font-size:32px;
}
Body {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font-family:"Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.innhold {
    display: table;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: white;
}

img {
    margin: 3px;
    width: 35%;
    float:right;
    padding:10px;
    margin: -257px 13px 0 0;
}
p{
    text-align: justify;
    width: 309px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
 .topboks {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 3em;
    width: 74%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.boks {
    background-color: white;
    width: 74%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper {
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

See --- [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Harpreet_devgun/dbqkv2L0/)